# Design Pattern for Iterator with Pagination with Java

Tags: java, pagination, iterator

I'm attempting to make service calls to an API that returns back results in a paged format and want suggestions on the design pattern for the iterator for this.

What I have till now is something like this

```
public class CustomIterator implements Iterator<Type> {

 private List<Result> results;
 private Service service;

 private int index;
 private int paginatedResultSize;
 private int totalResultsSize;

 public CustomIterator(Service service) {
  this.service = service;
  this.index = 0;
  this.results = getResults(index);
  this.totalResultsSize = this.results.totalResultsSize();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean hasNext() {
   if (index < totalResultsSize)
    return true;
   return false;
 }

 @Override
 public Type next() {

  if(index == paginatedResultSize) {
   getResults(index);
  }

  return results[index++];

 }

 private List<Result> getResults(index) throws Exception {
  this.results = service.makeServiceCall(index);
  this.paginatedResultSize = this.results.size();
  return this.results;
 }

}
```

Now, I understand that the purpose of the iterator is normally to just iterate, but I also want to encapsulate the whole pagination into a separate area so my client class can just call .next() on the class and get all values without having to know about the internal pagination details. Is there a clean pattern to getting this done?

With this the first issue I ran into was that the service call was throwing a checked exception and next() obviously does not.

Some options I noticed on the internet were to have this throw a RunTimeException which I'd rather only do as a last resort since I like checked exceptions for service calls. My gut feeling is that the service call should be done in a separate layer completely, but I'm not sure how the iterator will work with that pagination there. Any suggestions/links appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfectly acceptable approach.

How you handle exceptions is up to you. If the exception is something like `AttemptToReadBeyondLimit` then just return `false` from `hasNext`. If it is something like `CommunicationsException` then by all means throw a `RuntimeException`.

You shouldnt add extra layers unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback oldcurmudgeon. I did read up that using a RunTimeException isn't necessarily bad, but I was wondering if there was some other design pattern (maybe not even using an iterator) that encapsulates this sort of behaviour and also allows me to use checked exceptions for the service call since I'd like the client to not have to know about the exceptions and have it checked for them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the common usage of the `Iterator` design-pattern API requires the `next` method to be *safe*. So you will seldom **not** see this kind of code:

```
for(... iter. hasNext() ...) {
    Type t = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

So, I think you should keep that in mind when you design your `Iterator`-`Service` proxy. A misuse I currently see is the one you mentioned - about `next()` throwing an exception.

I would try to find a way to check the exception by doing one of two things:

1. **Creating a "flag" in the service API** - which means you will now have two services available, one called "isMoreDataAvailable" and the other called "getData".

   2. **Making an inner container** - which means the `hasNext` method will **actually** fetch the data from the service, and store it in an inner data-structure for the `next` method to get when called.

The downside of the **first** approach is the issue of redesigning the service API - not something that is always possible or backwards-compatible. The downside of the **second** approach is de-facto breaking the "Lazy" trait of the `hasNext` method, because now it will do a-lot more than just checking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion MordechayS. Unfortunately I can't redesign the API as I don't get to write it. Regarding your second point, wouldn't that add a checked exception now to the hasNext() as well which also is an issue?

Comment: @Rahul Youre welcome. Keep it simple - if your `try-catch` clause in the `hasNext` method goes off, log the error and use a `finally` clause to return `false`. Keep in mind that actual enviroment problems (like communication problems, mentioned in the second answer...) should throw a runtime exception...

Comment: Thanks mordechays. I would want to sort of "fail fast" however instead of just returning false to let the client know that the service call has actually failed instead of there actually not being any more data since it gives them the chance to possibly retry if there was a failure instead of falsely thinking they have traversed all the data.

Comment: @Rahul That's what I mean. hasNext returning false = no more data to traverse. hasNext returning true = there is more data. Other values (an Enum [True,False,Error] as a return value? An exception?) - As your designfull wishes.